# Stopping a long query - key command

Tags: sql, db2

When querying a large table, I'll often do:

`select * from table fetch first 50 rows only;`

to limit the results.

If I accidentally do a:

`select * from large_table`

and need to stop the query, if I hit `CTRL+C`, it logs me out of the db2 prompt. Is there a key command to just stop the query, and keep my session?

edit: this is all from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you can use [CANCEL QUERY](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010089.htm) command.